# how to stop user adding number to NumericUpDown after it reach a vlaue

Tags: vb.net, numericupdown

I have 10 NumericUpDowns. I want them when to reach the limit of 14 and then the last NumericUpDown the user clicked only can be decreased or stay the same after the msgbox display, I set the limit to each is 4

```
Private Sub Chkval()
        Dim storeval(11) As Integer
        storeval(0) = NumericUpDown1.Value
        storeval(1) = NumericUpDown2.Value
        storeval(2) = NumericUpDown3.Value
        storeval(3) = NumericUpDown4.Value
        storeval(4) = NumericUpDown5.Value
        storeval(5) = NumericUpDown6.Value
        storeval(6) = NumericUpDown13.Value
        storeval(7) = NumericUpDown14.Value
        storeval(8) = NumericUpDown18.Value
        storeval(9) = NumericUpDown19.Value
        If storeval.Sum > 14 Then
            MsgBox("ok")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Think about what you're asking for. When the `Value` changes in one control, you want to set the maximum `Value` that can be selected in other controls. Is there an event that's raised when the `Value` property changes? Is there a property that determines the maximum for the `Value` property?

Comment: Please include the detailed code. There's a lot of missing details in your question.

Comment: sorry my question may be a little confusing and my code as well, so I have 10 NUM and I want to check if the value for two of them add up together reaches 14, then the last one NUM the user clicks after the MSGbox displayed dont increase a number i want something can stop the NUM kepping going up after  Msgbox displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just hook all the 10 numericupdowns' ValueChanged event to a single event handler and in that handler check if the sum of all the values has exceeded 14. If so, then decrease the sender numericupdown's value so that the sum = 14.

Comment: I tried that, but what I want to achieve is that when the value is greater than 14 , it decreases the last numericupdown vlaue